# knockout custom element template depends on observables

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

After reading about [custom element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html) in new knockout 3.2 I tried to make something useful and not really straight-forward with it.

I tried to make a pagination element, which will have a current element and will allow user to select page from currentpage - 2 to currentpage + 2.

The problem is that in comparison to KO examples, my template depends on observables. So I tried to overcome it by creating pureComputed and generating template inside of it. But this does not allow me to add callback on clicking the elements.

```
ko.components.register('pagination', {
viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    this.page       = ko.observable(5);
    this.maxPage    = ko.observable(6);
    this.callback   = function(i){
        console.log(i);
    }
    this.template   = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        var page    = self.page(),
            minTmp  = page - 2,
            min     = minTmp < 1 ? 1 : minTmp,
            maxTmp  = page + 2,
            max     = maxTmp > self.maxPage() ? self.maxPage() : maxTmp,
            i, html = '';

        for (i = min; i <= max; i++){
            html += (i === page) ? '<li class="active"><a>'+i+'</a>':
            '<li data-bind="click: function(i){ callback(i) }"><a>'+i+'</a>';
        }
        return '<li><a href="#">«</a></li>'+ html +'<li><a href="#">»</a></li>';
    });
},
template: '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm" data-bind="html: template"></ul>'
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sytcbec/). In real code `this.page` and `this.maxPage` will be taken from params. I have no idea how can I make all this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your template depends on observables, try using these observables in the template itself instead of building the template in a for loop:

```
ko.components.register('pagination', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        var self = this;
        this.min        = ko.observable(params.min || 1);
        this.max        = ko.observable(params.max || 10);
        this.page       = ko.observable(5);
        this.maxPage    = ko.observable(6);
        this.callback   = function(i){
            console.log(i);
        };
    },
    template: '<ul class="pagination pagination-sm" data-bind="foreach: new Array(max() - min())"><li data-bind="css: { active: $index() + 1 === $parent.page() }, click: function() { $parent.callback($index() + 1) }"><a data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></a></ul>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thvnwLs5/1/

**Edit:**

[There are different ways of specifying a template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#specifying-a-template). One way is to define an element:

```
<template id="pagination-tpl">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm" data-bind="foreach: new Array(max() - min())">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $index() + 1 === $parent.page() }, click: function() { $parent.page($index() + 1) }">
            <a data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

And specify it like this `template: { element: 'pagination-tpl' }`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/thvnwLs5/3/

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this without putting everything in the template?

Comment: Defining your UI-logic inside your html / templates is the knockout way of doing things, so that's probably the preferred way. There are however others ways to define/specify your template; see my edit.